# Eeeek - rep arrow disappeared from Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Arrow is present on meta
[image: Arrow is present on meta]

but not on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) [image: but not on Area 51]

Not even an envelope!

Comment: How many [memes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) can one question contain?!

Comment: Erm, two? Freehand circles and "Eeeek!".

Comment: @Cody - and burnify (or was it burniate?). And a semi point for mentioning envelopes without getting the question deleted... yet! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just added the dropdown to Area 51.

Like the rest of the SE network, it features profile/activity/privileges/logout links, posts on which you recently gained or lost reputation, as well as badges earned in the past 24 hours.

However, it doesn't yet show a grid of reputation and revisions in the past day/week/month. We'll likely add it in the future, perhaps more urgently if people request it.